# problem with DVI adapter using Intel HD graphic with ubuntu-desktop

Tags: dvi

First I installed a fresh Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS and second installed the ubuntu-desktop. The problem is that on the DVI adapter of the mainboard the monitor stays black after the boot routine. Only when connecting the HDMI adapter with the monitor shows the login and desktop screen. So the question is why the DVI adapter doesn't work? Can xrandr command do something to activate the DVI and if yes how to do? Or is there another way to do it?

Hardware:
Mainboard with 1x DVI, 1x HDMI, 1x Displayport
CPU Intel Core i7-8700 with integrated graphics

Comment: Using the DVI adapter, if you type in your password (blind) at the login screen, does the monitor regain a signal?

Comment: No. The monitor stays black and the keyboard typing has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the DVI port is not enabled in the motherboard BIOS settings. Depending on your board and config, you may need to go into the settings and enable DVI.

Comment: After looking deeper into the BIOS settings I changed the graphic settings from "auto" to "IGFX" and now the DVI works. So the problem was that without this "auto" setting the DVI has used the onboard graphic instead.

Answer (score 0):

The DVI port is enabled, the installation routine worked normal on the DVI. This problem happened after the finished installation. When the server is booting than you can see the boot logs, until just before the services are starting the monitor became black. And here when using the HDMI port the monitor shows the screen. So something happens with the DVI while the boot process.